# How to wait until page loading image disappears in Protractor on non-Angular page

Tags: javascript, protractor, gif, loader

On non-Angular site when I click on certain radio button, page loading gif appears. In Protractor test I want to wait until this loader gif disappears and then check for another element.

HTML of the loader (which is ever present):

```
<div class="loader" style="display: none;">
    <div id="loader">
        <img src="/img/loading.gif">
    </div>
    <div class="totalMaskForLoader"></div>
</div>
```

What I have done in test:

```
        ...
        //  click on balance dropdown
        page.sortByBalanceSelector.click();

        browser.wait(function() {
                    // return a boolean here. Wait for spinner to be gone.
                    return !browser.isElementPresent(by.css(".loader"));
                }, 20000);

        // compare to the starting player's username
        expect(page.hasText(page.usernameCellButton)).not.toContain(startingUsername);
```

The problem is that I always get

> Wait timed out after 20009ms

How can I wait for loader gif to disappear?

Comment: `return !browser.isElementPresent(by.css(".loader"));` why do you use `not` here?

Comment: I see your point as I've copied this solution and wasn't noticing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a built-in [`invisibilityOf`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.invisibilityOf) Expected Condition specifically for this use case:

```
page.sortByBalanceSelector.click();

var loader = element(by.id("loader"));
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

browser.wait(EC.invisibilityOf(loader), 5000);
```

You may also use [`stalenessOf`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.stalenessOf) which basically means "not present".

---

The problem with your current approach is that you are applying the "not" to the promise returned by `isElementPresent()`, and, since *a promise is always truthy*, you are always getting "false" as a result of a wait condition, hence the timeout error.

Comment: Problem solved! THANK YOU! I've used `browser.wait(EC.invisibilityOf(loader), 5000);` and it did the charm. Can someone point me to a doc or page where all Protractor Expected conditions are explained?

Comment: Stupid me, no need for a link to page where Expected conditions are explained as Protractor page has it covered: http://www.protractortest.org/#/api.